# Changing font of part of string in forestplot

Tags: r, expression, r-forestplot

Below there is a forestplot, created with the package forestplot in R.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFjFu.png)

I created it using the following code:

```
library("forestplot")
data(HRQoL)
clrs <- fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue")
tabletext <- cbind(rownames(HRQoL$Sweden),
                   paste("r=", sprintf("%.2f", HRQoL$Sweden[,"coef"])))

forestplot(tabletext, 
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = list(gpar(fontfamily = "Times", fontface="italic"),
                                         gpar(fontfamily = "",
                                              col = "blue")),
                            ticks = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex=1),
                            xlab  = gpar(fontfamily = "HersheySerif", cex = 1.5)),
           rbind(HRQoL$Sweden),
           col=clrs,
           xlab="EQ-5D index")
```

As one can see, I managed to change the fontface to italics for the whole first column. But what I would like to do is to change the r in the second column to italics, leaving the numbers in the normal fontface. Is that possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. It was not easy, as I needed to convert the matrix (which can not have different types of variables) into multiple lists and sublists. Then it is possible to store at the corresponding index an `expression` in a new list. Expressions can save different formatting. Unfortunately they cannot evaluate variables, so indexing of other variables has to be done via the `substitute` function. Very tricky, I don't know if there is a more elegant way, but it works.

Another, maybe easier option might be to use unicode (also included in the example code), but I found this to tricky.

Hope the code helps:

```
library("forestplot")
data(HRQoL)
clrs <- fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue")

tabletext <- list(list(), list()) #Creating a list with "sublists" for each column
tabletext[[1]] <- rownames(HRQoL$Sweden)
tabletext[[2]][1] <- list(expression(paste(italic("r"), " = .42"))) #manual way using expression and paste
tabletext[[2]][2] <- list(substitute(expression(paste(italic("r"),"=",r_string)), list(r_string=HRQoL$Sweden[,2]))) #need substitute function to access variables
tabletext[[2]][3] <- list(substitute(expression(paste(italic("r"),"=",r_string)), list(r_string=sprintf("%.3f", HRQoL$Sweden[,3])))) #The substitute functions allows addicitonal manipulation of strings to be put back into the expression
tabletext[[2]][4] <- list(substitute(expression(paste(italic("t")[df],"=",r_string)), list(r_string=sprintf("%.3f", HRQoL$Sweden[,3]), df="23"))) #One can also substitute multiple elements of expression, use subscripts etc. 

tabletext[[1]][2] <- "Use unicode: \u03B2" #Manipulate strings manually, using unicode
tabletext[[1]][4] <- list(expression(bold("Make single line bold"))) #Manipulate strings manually, using unicode


forestplot(tabletext, 
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = list(gpar(fontfamily = "Times", fontface="italic"),
                                         gpar(fontfamily = "",
                                              col = "blue")),
                            ticks = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex=1),
                            xlab  = gpar(fontfamily = "HersheySerif", cex = 1.5)),
           rbind(HRQoL$Sweden),
           col=clrs,
           xlab="EQ-5D index")
```

I tried to explain the different steps in the code. If you want to type manual strings, you don't need the substitute function. Important: Whenever expression is used, you need to create a new list. Maybe there is a more elegant way using the `parse` function, but this one works.

[So the plot with different formatting within a field looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Gr4.png)

Comment: This has been very helpful for me and thanks for all the examples you provide! And if others need to do this and are also no R experts: when you need an integer within a variable to be italic, you can just reference it in the italic function, but must have converted the integer to a string first. So e.g. list(substitute(expression(paste(italic(integer_to_str))), list(integer_to_string=sprintf("%.3f", DF$int_var[1]))))