# How to make multiple elements italic in foresplot()

Tags: r, r-forestplot

Similar questions have been asked multiple times ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588972/modify-font-of-single-element-in-forestplot), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68671453/making-single-element-bold-in-forestplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229334/changing-font-of-part-of-string-in-forestplot)). However, I don't get it to work in my case.

So I have this code (see below) and I want to make all elements from the "column" `Gene` italic, except the header (`Gene`) and the summary(`Cancer`).

Using `expression(italic())` raises an `could not find function "italic"` Error. I guess, I have to use `fp_txt_italic()` or `txt_gp` here somehow, but I just don't get how they work. Maybe someone could enlighten me :).

My code (simplified, since the original is a bit more complex):

```
library(forestplot)
library(dplyr)


mean <- c(0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0 )
lower <- c(0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 0.9 )
upper <- c(1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.1 )
gene <- c("TP53", "KRAS", "CBP", "Cancer")
p_value <- c(0.06, 0.05, 0.01, 0.05 )
n_pos <- c(30, 40, 35, 50)
n_neg  <- c(470, 460, 465, 450)


base_data <- tibble(mean = mean,
                    lower = lower,
                    upper = upper,
                    gene = gene,
                    n_pos = n_pos,
                    n_neg = n_neg,
                    p_value = p_value)


base_data |>
  filter(gene != "Cancer") |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(gene, n_pos, n_neg, p_value),
             xlog = TRUE,
             vertices = TRUE,
             txt_gp = fpTxtGp(
               label = list(
                 grid::gpar(fontface = "italic"),
                 grid::gpar()))) |>
  fp_append_row(mean  = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$mean,
                lower = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$lower,
                upper = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$upper,
                gene = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$gene,
                n_pos = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$n_pos,
                n_neg = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$n_neg,
                p_value = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$p_value,
                is.summary = TRUE) |>
  fp_add_header(gene = c("Gene\n"),
                n_pos = c("n(mutated)\n"),
                n_neg = c("n(wildtype)\n"),
                p_value = c("p\n")) |>
  fp_set_zebra_style("#EFEFEF") |>
  fp_add_lines() |>
  fp_decorate_graph(graph.pos = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73268030/12993861) you can use the `txt_gp=` argument of `forestplot` to

> Set the fonts etc for all text elements.

using an object of class `fpTxtGp`. To create this object you can use the `fpTxtGp()` function which via the `label=` argument allows to set the fonts etc. for the text labels using `grid::gpar()`. Besides setting one font etc. for all text labels you can set the fonts individually for each column or for each element.

In the code below I target the columns by passing a 2 element `list`, i.e. for the first column I set `fontface = "italic"` while for the second column I use the defaults.

```r
library(forestplot)
library(tidyverse)

base_data |>
  filter(gene != "Cancer") |>
  forestplot(
    labeltext = c(gene, p_value),
    xlog = TRUE,
    vertices = TRUE,
    txt_gp = fpTxtGp(
      label = list(
        grid::gpar(fontface = "italic"),
        grid::gpar()
      )
    )
  ) |>
  fp_append_row(
    mean = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$mean,
    lower = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$lower,
    upper = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$upper,
    gene = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$gene,
    p_value = filter(base_data, gene == "Cancer")$p_value,
    is.summary = TRUE
  ) |>
  fp_add_header(
    gene = c("Gene\n"),
    p_value = c("p\n")
  ) |>
  fp_set_zebra_style("#EFEFEF") |>
  fp_add_lines() |>
  fp_decorate_graph(graph.pos = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: That actually works for the posted example. However, I have some more columns in my plot (updated the code above). Your code is applied to every other column so that the new `n_neg` column is also italic now. Any way, to restrict it to this one column (`Gene`) only?

Comment: Well, each element in the list targets one column. When you pass a list of two elements with four columns, the `list` gets recycled to match the number of columns. Instead, with four columns use a `list` of four elements, e.g. use `label = c(list(grid::gpar(fontface = "italic")), replicate(3, grid::gpar()))`